# Beginner: ASP.NET window output html takes long time

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, iis-6, cpu

The web site that I have run for long time, sometimes it will have some speed issues, but after we clean up the MSSQL data, it will work fine.

But this time, it doesn't work any more, we always got Timeout error, and the IIS causes the CPU runs very high.

We took out some features, and the site runs back OK, but slow without error.

For example, when we do a search, if we have less than 10 results, the page/output is really fast.

When we have more than 200 results, the page is very slow, almost take about 15 to 20 secs to output the whole page

I know if you have more data to output, of course it takes more time to run, but we used to have more than 500 results, it ran/output very fast also.

Do you know anywhere I should look at to solve this speed problem?

Comment: There are one trilion of possible sources. Without seeing some code it's impossible to help you.

Comment: @Dolly Chan: try to mark answers for Your previous questions. people are less likely to help You here if You do not do that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the code to see what is executed with displaying those results. Implement some logging or step through the execution of a result with a debugger.

If you have a source control system, now is the time to review what changes have been made between fast code and now slow code.

10 results could be taking 1 second to display which is barely tolerable but as you say 200 results takes 20 seconds. So the problem is some bad code somewhere. I think someone has made a code change.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with breaking down the issue. For example sql server times and iis times. You can separate different parts of code and measure execution times, etc.

[SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx) is good tool to start with and for ASP.NET You can start with simple [trace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386420.aspx) and [page tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94c55d08.aspx).

Some more info about [testing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924375.aspx) and [performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649152.aspx)